# How to include es5-shim in browserify bundle

Tags: browserify, es5-shim

Should I do something like the following in my entry point:

var es5Shim = require('es5-shim');

That gets included properly in the bundle but it just seems like there has to be a better way and I'm missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -r to require additional dependencies:

```
$ browserify -r "es5-shim" ...
```